# Using Requests to pull PDF from PHP link

Tags: php, python, html, pdf, python-requests

First attempt at web scraping and at a bit of loss on the final 10% of my problem.

Is there some trick to getting a php linked download with requests that I'm missing?

I am trying to pull a number of PDFs from a conference's proceedings page that is a php page. I can successfully login and navigate to all the individual pages where the PDF files are linked using Selenium (1st time, remember, so I like seeing the pages get navigated) and can pull the titles for all the papers. I am then trying the following to get the contents of the link.

```
# Get the links
pdfLinks = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for pdfItem in range(len(pdfLinks)):
    if re.search('loadPDF', pdfLinks[pdfItem].get_attribute('href')):
        print(pdfLinks[pdfItem].text)
```

The above code identifies all the link text correctly, so far so good.

```
# Trying to prove out a simple save
for pdfItem in range(len(pdfLinks)):
    if re.search('session-5.5', pdfLinks[pdfItem].get_attribute('href')):
        print('Requesting "{0:s}" from {1:s}'.format(pdfLinks[pdfItem].text, str(pdfLinks[pdfItem].get_attribute('href'))))
        res = requests.get(pdfLinks[pdfItem].get_attribute('href'), stream=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'firefox'})
        res.raise_for_status()
        pdfFile = open('{0:s}.pdf'.format(pdfLinks[pdfItem].text), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            pdfFile.write(chunk)
        pdfFile.close()
```

The response header I get from this is:

```
{'content-length': '112', 'date': 'Tue, 07 Jul 2015 13:46:27 GMT', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'set-cookie': 'PHPSESSID=7d62686unhha7q0muh4u41pe27; path=/', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'accept-ranges': 'none', 'server': 'Apache'}
```

I've tried this same code deleting the `res.raise_for_status()` and `stream=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'firefox'}` bits without success.

If I physically click the link and check the GET request in the browser console I see REQUEST HEADER and SENT COOKIE information followed by the RESPONSE HEADER of:

```
Response Headers Δ81ms
Server: Apache
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Date:   Tue, 07 Jul 2015 14:23:25 GMT
Content-Type:   application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary
Content-Length: 1160565
Content-Disposition:    inline; filename="Custom file name for the.pdf"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
```

So the deltas appear to be that a cookie is getting sent along with the GET on a physical click.

The code may be verbose, but I'm trying to learn first and optimize later. At this point it would have been faster to click on every link and rename the files, but I'd like to know how this works.

Appreciate any pointers to help guide me.

Comment: Did you try to 1) capture the conversation with Wireshark or 2) Enable debugging in Requests? Though I can't be sure, this might be an issue with automatic redirection. At "The response header I get from this is:", what is the body of the message?

Comment: @jcoppens From `res = requests.get(pdfLinks[pdfItem].get_attribute('href'), stream=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'firefox'})` the body of the message is simply: `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.advancedautobat.com"></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Didn't know what Wireshark was until I just looked it up. Seems like overkill for this problem, but perhaps worth a look. I have not tried enabling debugging in Requests, will investigate.

Comment: The url in the body seems to indicate that the page will redirect to that new url, in 0 seconds. This from [metatags](http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_refresh) I don't know `refresh` very well, but the url in the body seems to indicate that the page will redirect to that new url, in 0 seconds. I know Requests follows actual redirects (if enabled), but I don't now if it follows refresh.

Comment: Yes, Wireshark is rather large. However it is easy to use, and practical to have laying around if you do protocol work. I've done some sneaky debugging on a similar project, and was very happy to have it.